# Suggest communities that a user may want to follow

Tags: mysql, select, join

I want to suggest communities that a user may want to follow, like "People you may know" on Facebook or "Who to follow" on Twitter.

For example:

Communities: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

User A follows: 1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14

User B follows: 1,2,4,10,11,12,13,14

User H follows: 1,4,8

User C follows: 5,6,7

User D follows: 5,6,7

User E follows: 5,6,7

User F follows: 5,6,7

User G follows: 5,6,7

User I follows: 5,6,7

User J follows: 5,6,7

Let’s suggest the user A the communities he may want to follow:

4,8,5,6,7,9

Is more likely the user A may want to follow the community 4 than the others, because the user B follows it and they have a very similar interest.

The problem is that my query doesn’t return communities that hasn't at least one user that follow another community as user A. In this case, would return only:

4,8

My Query - SQL Fiddle:
http://bit.ly/MF9Lve

How can I solve it?

Comment: You might want to look into triadic closure

Comment: I've never heard about it, I'll take a look. My query is almost working, I just can't figure out what I've to change to work 100%!

Comment: @ClaudiusIbn Your fiddle was broken for awhile today, and it was my fault.  I had recently deployed a small tweak to the logic for mysql and it broke yours because of your comments.  I've just now rolled out a fix for that, so it is working again.  Sorry about that!